# Kafka.Utils.createRDD Vs KafkaDirectStreaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I would like to know if the read operations from a Kafka queue is faster by using batch-Kafka RDD instead of the KafkaDirectStream when I want to read all the Kafka queue.

I've observed that reading from different partition with batch RDD is not resulting in Spark concurrent jobs. Is there some Spark proprierties to config in order to allow this behaviour?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your spark consumers in different threads or as different processes. That's the approach I take. I've observed that I get the best concurrency by allocating one consumer thread (or process) per topic partition.

Regarding your questions about batch vs KafkaDirectStream, I think even KafkaDirectStream is batch oriented.  The batch interval can be specified in the streaming context, like this:

```
private static final int INTERVAL = 5000;  // 5 seconds
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, new Duration(INTERVAL));
```

There's a good image that described how spark streaming is batch oriented here:

http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/streaming-programming-guide.html#discretized-streams-dstreams

Answer (score 0):

Spark is essentially a batch engine and Spark streaming takes batching closer to streaming by defining something called micro-batching. Micro-batching is nothing but specifying batch interval to be very low (can be as low as 50ms per the advice in the official documentation). So now all it matters is how much is your micro-batch interval going to be. If you keep it low, you would feel it is near real-time.

On the Kafka consumer front, Spark direct receiver runs as a separate task in each executor. So if you have enough executors as the partitions, then it fetches data from all partitions and creates an RDD out of it.

If you are talking about reading from multiple queues, then you would create multiple DStreams, which would again need more executors to match the total number of partitions.